# validatation of phone number and email id fields with angular js(using scope) and HTML?(error message should be displayed)

Tags: html, angularjs

I need HTML and Angular JS Code for phone number and Email ID validation
Phone Number should be 10 digit 
it is the required field 
these error messages shouls be displaYED

Comment: You can delete your question, but i refer to have a tour on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question without get navigate points

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txt_email" runat-"server" clientidmode="static" onblur="return emailvalidate(this.id)"/>

<input type="text" id="txt_mobile" runat-"server" clientidmode="static" onblur="return mobilevalidate(this.id)"/>
```

**jquery**

```
function emailvalidate(tboxid) {
    var userinput = $("#" + tboxid).val();
    if (userinput != "") {
        var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
        if (filter.test(userinput)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $("#" + tboxid).attr("data-original-title", "'" + userinput + "' Invalid E-mail Address! Please re-enter.");
            $("#" + tboxid).val('');
            $("#" + tboxid).focus()
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function mobilevalidate(tboxid) {
    var userinput = $("#" + tboxid).val();
    if (userinput != "") {
        var filter = /^\d{10}$/;
        if (filter.test(userinput)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $("#" + tboxid).attr('data-original-title', 'Please Enter Valid Mobile Number');
            $("#" + tboxid).val('');
            $("#" + tboxid).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try answer with `angularjs` pattern, as `ng-pattern` or something like that, you will get point faster, `onblur` or ... related to jQuery.

Comment: I need angualrjs not Jquery